# Can't retrieve document data in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this function set to await for new document `onCreate` event.

I have checked that my doc fields are correct:
this is the structure of my collection/Documents: `users/{userID}/...`

```
{
    appVersion: [String]
    displayName: [String]
    email: [String]
    isUserBlocked: [bool]
    lastOnline: [timeStamp]
    photoUrl: [String]
    uid: [String]
    ...
}
```

[image]

```
Function for detecting new documents
// detects new users added
exports.newUserCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userID}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    // New document Created

    const user = snap.data();

    console.log(user.displayName); // logs 'undefined'
    console.log(user.uid); // logs 'undefined

    return;
  });
```

This is the result of the 2 console.logs
[image]

Comment: If you're logging things, you should also show those lines of code as well as the specific output they generate.  "seems to not show any field" is not very specific - show the specific output of the logs in your query.

Comment: Also, you're not paying attention to the promises returned by sentToDevice, so that will cause other problems with messages not being sent.  The function should return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is fully complete.

Comment: edit: showed picture with lines of log from the Object.keys loop log. Will also add then and catches to sentToDevice. But I'm sure this has nothing to do with the payload error.

Comment: Which of those lines are a result of each line of logging code?  Please be clear about *where those lines of logging code are in your function*, and *how the output matches those lines*.  If you have errors, you should expand them to show in more detail.  I suggest trimming this code down to the bare minimum that doesn't work the way you expect so you can better isolate the issue.  It looks like you're dealing with too much extra stuff for the purpose of debugging.  I strongly suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson done.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed what was my problem, right after creating the document, my app was updating the document, it's possible this had issues with the firebase functions. my bad.

edit: fixed that and the issue still persists. I am inclined to believe this is the issue:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_firebaseUser.uid).set(
          _userDataMap,
          SetOptions(merge: true), // <---- this merge option might be messing with the cloud function trigger
        );
```

I am going to test this and update.

edit: Still testing why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

At the moment this is the hack I am using:

```
// detects new users added
exports.newUserCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userID}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    let sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    // New document Created

    await sleep(500);

    // get admins if no admins return
    const adminUsers = await db
      .collection("users")
      .where("userType", "==", "admin")
      .get();

    if (adminUsers.empty) {
      return;
    }

    // console.log(snap.id);

    const thisDoc = await db.collection("users").doc(snap.id).get();

    var user;

    if (!thisDoc.exists) {
      console.log("No such document!");
      return null;
    } else {
      // console.log("Document data:", thisDoc.data());
      // Object.keys(thisDoc.data()).forEach((prop) =>
      // console.log(`key: ${prop}`)
      // );
      user = thisDoc.data();
    }

    // get and set data for notification/msg
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Nuevo Usuario Creado!",
        body: `Dar Acceso (Desbloquear) a ${user.displayName}?`,
        icon: user.photoUrl,
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      },
      data: {
        userName: user.displayName,
        userID: user.uid,
      },
    };

    var adminTokens = [];
    // loop all admins get their token and send the notification/msg
    adminUsers.forEach((doc) => {
      adminTokens.push(doc.data().token);
    });

    admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToDevice(adminTokens, payload)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });

    return null;
  });
```

Basically, it detects a new doc, but since I can't seem to extract the data from the same doc, I have to use a get method to get the data. (yes I know it looks stupid but it works atm)

Comment: I hope this is not a long shot, I've been playing with the code of your post (the one that is much more simpler) could you try to ad .toString()? to me it seems that is getting an undefined as it is not converting it to a string. maybe you could try it out?

Comment: I meant to add console.log(user.displayName.toString());
It is working for me every time

Comment: @Luis Manual it does work 100% if you add the document manually on the firestore. But it seem to have issues if done with Flutter app. I don't understand why.

Comment: you know when u add a document to a collection, the new document flashes green for like a split second. But my Flutter code (which is the same as how their api says) flashes green for less than a split of a second. I believe there is a problem with it.

Comment: Hey, I've been trying with different clients... so I'm not sure if this could be due to the size of you document or the root cause of this...

Please could you use the next logs just to verify?

const user = snap.data();
console.log(user.name.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // this should print the object as a whole... I would just like to se what is it printing to you

Comment: @LuisManuel no luck, it's undefined, I have no idea how to fix this. It seems the object is still undefined which is why .toString() does not work. https://i.imgur.com/OENgBlG.png